# pdfjs in Android WebView crashes on scroll

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, pdf.js

i've added pdf.js to my Android Project (Visual Studio 2015, Xamarin), to display a pdf in a WebView Component. With the following Cod loads an example pdf.

```
        WebView wv = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
        wv.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        wv.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        wv.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
        wv.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/viewer.html?file=http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf");
```

But as soon as i try to scroll down the pdf, the whole app crashes. The following lines are from the debug log.

> Loaded assembly: System.dll [External]
>   Der Thread 'Unknown' (0x2) hat mit Code 0 (0x0) geendet.
>   01-08 11:41:48.763 W/cr.BindingManager( 5994): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 5994
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The provided value 'moz-chunked-arraybuffer' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType.", source:  (0)
>   01-08 11:41:49.359 I/chromium( 5994): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The provided value 'moz-chunked-arraybuffer' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType.", source:  (0)
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(946)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/viewer.js (946)
>   01-08 11:41:49.540 I/chromium( 5994): [INFO:CONSOLE(946)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/viewer.js (946)
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Handler added to rejected promise", source: file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/viewer.html?file=http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf (0)
>   01-08 11:41:49.565 W/cr.BindingManager( 5994): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 5994
>   01-08 11:41:49.565 I/chromium( 5994): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Handler added to rejected promise", source: file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/viewer.html?file=http://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf (0)
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(7007)] "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/viewer.js (7007)
>   01-08 11:41:49.566 I/chromium( 5994): [INFO:CONSOLE(7007)] "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/viewer.js (7007)
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(946)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/viewer.js (946)
>   01-08 11:41:49.607 I/chromium( 5994): [INFO:CONSOLE(946)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/viewer.js (946)
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(7104)] "PDF c21f21ea44c1e2ed2581435fa5a2dcce [1.6 Acrobat Distiller 7.0.5 (Windows) / Acrobat PDFMaker 7.0.7 for Word] (PDF.js: 1.2.109)", source: file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/viewer.js (7104)
>   01-08 11:41:49.607 I/chromium( 5994): [INFO:CONSOLE(7104)] "PDF c21f21ea44c1e2ed2581435fa5a2dcce [1.6 Acrobat Distiller 7.0.5 (Windows) / Acrobat PDFMaker 7.0.7 for Word] (PDF.js: 1.2.109)", source: file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/viewer.js (7104)
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(946)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/viewer.js (946)
>   01-08 11:41:49.667 I/chromium( 5994): [INFO:CONSOLE(946)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/viewer.js (946)

This is a snippet from the viewer.js function (Line 946)

```
    _readFromStorage: function ViewHistory_readFromStorage() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    resolve(localStorage.getItem('database')); (Line 946)
  });
},
```

Does anyone has an idea ?

Comment: I have already tried to set .setDomStorageEnabled(true); but i doest work either..

Comment: Did you tried it in a simple android browser? I don't think it's a Xamarin bug, it looks more like a Android bug.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an Android issue.Try enabling the DOM storage.

```
wv.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Webkit.WebSettings.DomStorageEnabled/